# How to link the subdirectories only with maximum digit folder using linux command?

Tags: files, file-management

I have the following directory structure and I need to remove the minimum linked directories and keep the maximum one using the command line. How can I do it?

My directory structure:

```
    prj38
    |-- DDR23
    |   |-- BSCAN
    |   |   |-- BSCAN.config
    |   |   |-- BSCAN.html
    |   |   |-- rev1
    |   |   |   |-- rev1.config
    |   |   |   `-- rev1.html
    |   |   |-- rev2
    |   |   |   |-- rev2.config
    |   |   |   `-- rev2.html
    |   |   `-- rev3
    |   |       |-- rev3.config
    |   |       `-- rev3.html
    |   |-- DDR23.config
    |   |-- DDR23.html
    |   `-- Timing_Analysis
    |       |-- Timing_Analysis.config
    |       |-- Timing_Analysis.html
    |       |-- rev1
    |       |   |-- rev1.config
    |       |   `-- rev1.html
    |       |-- rev2
    |       |   |-- rev2.config
    |       |   `-- rev2.html
    |       |-- rev14
    |       |   |-- rev14.config
    |       |   `-- rev14.html
```

Expected directory structure:

```
    prj38
    |-- DDR23
    |   |-- BSCAN
    |   |   |-- BSCAN.config
    |   |   |-- BSCAN.html
    |   |   |-- rev3
    |   |   |   |-- rev3.config
    |   |   |   `-- rev3.html
    |   |-- DDR23.config
    |   |-- DDR23.html
    |   `-- Timing_Analysis
    |       |-- Timing_Analysis.config
    |       |-- Timing_Analysis.html
    |       |-- rev14
    |       |   |-- rev14.config
    |       |   `-- rev14.html
```

I tried:

```
rm -rf  rev1
```

That command will help remove each directory separately by giving each directory name.

I want to do the same thing for multiple directories using one command. How can I do it?

Comment: Please don't add the "linux" tag just because you're using Linux. It should only be used for questions about the linux kernel. Also, sed isn't relevant at all here. Finally, I see you also reverted my edit to your title. What do you mean "link"? You don't seem to be asking for a link; the fact that you used `unlink` instead of `rm -rf` to remove the directory isn't relevant.

Comment: Okay .Then is there any other way to do for multiple folders.Even if i use rm -rf I cant do it everytime for each folders. @terdon